# svn st: how can a file be both `?` and `!`?

Tags: svn, version-control

When I run `svn st` in my repository directory, one file is listed twice with different codes in the first column:

```
!       myfile_(2001).csv
?       myfile_(2001).csv
```

The help page displayed with `svn st --help` states...

```
      '?' item is not under version control
      '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
```

These seem to be mutually exclusive codes, so I don't understand how one file can be labeled with both. Please explain how this circumstance might have arisen, and what is the best way to resolve it.

Comment: Maybe different filenames? For example trailing whitespaces? What say `svn status "myfile_(2001).csv"`?

Comment: `svn st "myfile_(2001).csv"` returns only `?       myfile_(2001).csv`. However, there is only one file with this name.

Comment: @uzsolt I did `hexdump`s of the different file names returned by `svn st`, and it looks like one of the characters is actually different. I should have thought of that. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You're welcome :D